# XSLT Union to combine datasets?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to parse my xml abit too much like a dataset and Have the following:

```
... 
        <InvestmentStrategy Id="Employee">
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund032" PctInvested="20.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund034" PctInvested="20.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund035" PctInvested="10.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund042" PctInvested="20.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Lifeasdstyle030" PctInvested="30.0000" />
        </InvestmentStrategy>
        <InvestmentStrategy Id="Employer">
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund092" PctInvested="20.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund094" PctInvested="20.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund095" PctInvested="10.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund092" PctInvested="20.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Lifasdestyle030" PctInvested="30.0000" />
        </InvestmentStrategy>

...

        <InvestmentAccount Id="Sequence001" Type="Standard" InvestmentStrategyId="Employee" ParameterOverrideIds="AllocationRateOverride">
          <Investment FundName="Fund092" FundValue="7395.91" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund094" FundValue="7222.72" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund095" FundValue="3903.52" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund098" FundValue="11051.32" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund092" FundValue="6602.54" />
        </InvestmentAccount>
        <InvestmentAccount Id="Sequence002" Type="Standard" InvestmentStrategyId="Employer" ParameterOverrideIds="AllocationRateOverride">
          <Investment FundName="Fund032" FundValue="4754.82" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund034" FundValue="4643.48" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund035" FundValue="2509.46" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund038" FundValue="7104.71" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund042" FundValue="4244.08" />
        </InvestmentAccount>
```

What I'd like to do is able about to 'select' all elemets where InvestmentStrategy/@Id is equal to InvestmentAccount/@InvestmentStrategyId

and loop around the combined data node. I have tried without much success 'unioning' the 2 and also something like

any clues? help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kacctByStratId" match="InvestmentAccount"
  use="@InvestmentStrategyId"/>

 <xsl:template match="InvestmentStrategy">
  <strategyData>
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="key('kacctByStratId', @Id)"/>
  </strategyData>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML** (wrapped in a top element to make it well-formed document):

```
<t>
        <InvestmentStrategy Id="Employee">
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund032" PctInvested="20.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund034" PctInvested="20.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund035" PctInvested="10.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund042" PctInvested="20.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Lifeasdstyle030" PctInvested="30.0000" />
        </InvestmentStrategy>
        <InvestmentStrategy Id="Employer">
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund092" PctInvested="20.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund094" PctInvested="20.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund095" PctInvested="10.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Fund092" PctInvested="20.0000" />
          <FundSplit FundName="Lifasdestyle030" PctInvested="30.0000" />
        </InvestmentStrategy>

...

        <InvestmentAccount Id="Sequence001" Type="Standard" InvestmentStrategyId="Employee" ParameterOverrideIds="AllocationRateOverride">
          <Investment FundName="Fund092" FundValue="7395.91" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund094" FundValue="7222.72" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund095" FundValue="3903.52" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund098" FundValue="11051.32" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund092" FundValue="6602.54" />
        </InvestmentAccount>
        <InvestmentAccount Id="Sequence002" Type="Standard" InvestmentStrategyId="Employer" ParameterOverrideIds="AllocationRateOverride">
          <Investment FundName="Fund032" FundValue="4754.82" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund034" FundValue="4643.48" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund035" FundValue="2509.46" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund038" FundValue="7104.71" />
          <Investment FundName="Fund042" FundValue="4244.08" />
        </InvestmentAccount>

</t>
```

**produces the wanted "combined data" result**:

```
<strategyData>
    <InvestmentStrategy Id="Employee">
        <FundSplit FundName="Fund032" PctInvested="20.0000" />
        <FundSplit FundName="Fund034" PctInvested="20.0000" />
        <FundSplit FundName="Fund035" PctInvested="10.0000" />
        <FundSplit FundName="Fund042" PctInvested="20.0000" />
        <FundSplit FundName="Lifeasdstyle030" PctInvested="30.0000" />
    </InvestmentStrategy>
    <InvestmentAccount Id="Sequence001" Type="Standard" InvestmentStrategyId="Employee" ParameterOverrideIds="AllocationRateOverride">
        <Investment FundName="Fund092" FundValue="7395.91" />
        <Investment FundName="Fund094" FundValue="7222.72" />
        <Investment FundName="Fund095" FundValue="3903.52" />
        <Investment FundName="Fund098" FundValue="11051.32" />
        <Investment FundName="Fund092" FundValue="6602.54" />
    </InvestmentAccount>
</strategyData>
<strategyData>
    <InvestmentStrategy Id="Employer">
        <FundSplit FundName="Fund092" PctInvested="20.0000" />
        <FundSplit FundName="Fund094" PctInvested="20.0000" />
        <FundSplit FundName="Fund095" PctInvested="10.0000" />
        <FundSplit FundName="Fund092" PctInvested="20.0000" />
        <FundSplit FundName="Lifasdestyle030" PctInvested="30.0000" />
    </InvestmentStrategy>
    <InvestmentAccount Id="Sequence002" Type="Standard" InvestmentStrategyId="Employer" ParameterOverrideIds="AllocationRateOverride">
        <Investment FundName="Fund032" FundValue="4754.82" />
        <Investment FundName="Fund034" FundValue="4643.48" />
        <Investment FundName="Fund035" FundValue="2509.46" />
        <Investment FundName="Fund038" FundValue="7104.71" />
        <Investment FundName="Fund042" FundValue="4244.08" />
    </InvestmentAccount>
</strategyData>
```

Comment: Thanks this is pretty close to what I wanted (taken in isolation it is perfect) Now I have to get this code into my existing template that already uses a template match and various loops etc to build up an XML DataSet. Any suggetions? Can this work without the template as I believe they can't be nested?      
<xsl:template match="/">
<DataSet>
...
<BASIC>
<MyField><xsl:value-of select="./Plan/@EndDate"/></MyField>
...
<strategyData Id = '{@Id}'>
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
<xsl:copy-of select="key('kacctByStratId', @Id)"/>
</strategyData>
...

Comment: I think I cracked it with a 'for-each'
    <teST>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Request/Inputs/Control/Plan/InvestmentStrategy">
        <xsl:variable name="Id" select="@Id"/>
        <strategyData Id = '{@Id}'>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="key('kacctByStratId', @Id)"/>
        </strategyData>
      </xsl:for-each>
      
    </teST>

Comment: @JonH: Yes, this is possible and you have found one way. I would certainly prefer `<xsl:apply-templates .../>` to `<xsl:for-each ... />`. Could you, please, consider accepting this answer? Also you can think of accepting my answer, which happens to be better than the one currently accepted,  to another of your questions.